# Is this a group $G=\mathbb{Z}$ with $a*b=4$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Okay! Well I know its not a group but for my own sake I'm having trouble explaining why and seeing why it isn't.

$G=\mathbb{Z}$ with $a*b=4$

I believe that it's not a group because Inverse Elements don't exist 
i.e.
$a*b=1$ no such $b \in G$ exists that'll, but apparently this isn't a proper explanation.

apparently the real answer is that there does not exist a proper identity, can someone explain why this fails?

Comment: For sure, the non existence of inverse elements is a good explanation

Comment: It is not immediately apparent that inverse elements don't exist, but it does require that 4 be the identity in your group.

Comment: "For sure, the non existence of inverse elements is a good explanation"  It is *not* a good explanation unless you know that $1$ is an identity element.  And as for $a\ne 4$ we have $1*a = a*1 = 4 \ne a$ we know that $1$ is *not* an identity element.  However we know that for $a \ne 4$ that $4*a =4\ne a$ so $4$ is not an identity element and for all $b$ we have $b*a = 4\ne $ an identity element so whatever the identity element is (if there is one--- which there isn't) then there is no inverse element for $a$.  And *that* is a good and valid argument.

Comment: No need to downvote.  This was a good question and the OP thought and tried to figure it out and had a decent attempt at an answer.  Why the answer was not correct is a valid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of an inverse element depends on the definition of an identity element. We can't assume that that the identity is $1$ in this group. So first we need to check if there exists some $e \in G$ such that for every $g \in G$, we have that $e * g = g = g * e$. And no such $e$ exists. Otherwise, we could take $g = 5$ to obtain:
$$
e * 5 = 5 \implies 4 = 5
$$
a contradiction.

Comment: I mean would't any a or b make that the equation true? so thats why i'm confused, technically the identity would be unique but it wouldnt exist no?>

Answer (score 2):

The reason the argument is not proper is because it assumes that $1$ is the identity element.

For $a \ne 4$ we have $1*a = 4 \ne a$ so $1$ is *not* an identity element.

Now we *can* fix this by saying:  If $G$ is a group than there will be an element $e$ that is an identity element.  At this time we don't know *what* $e$ actually is or even if such an $e$ *exists*.  But if $G$ is a group there is one.

Pick any $a,b \in \mathbb Z$.  $a*b =4$ so unless $4 = e$ we do *not* have $b = a^{-1}$.  For any $c \ne 4$ we have $4*c =4 \ne c$ so $4$ is not the identity element.  And therefore since $a*b = 4\ne e$ for all $b$, we know that $a$ can not have an inverse.

That *IS* a proper argument.

But it is an unnecessiarily complicated argument.

It'd be easier just to show that $G$ has no identity element.  Let $a \ne 4$, then for any element $e$ we have $a*e = 4\ne a$ so no possible $e$ can be an identity element.  So $G$ can not be a group.